# bcrypt using in laravel and python

Tags: php, python, django, laravel, crypt

I am using bcrypt in laravel with  round 10 for password and now i want to access my site from django framework and want to check password from there

```
when i hit with this sting 123456
it return me: $2y$10$leNO3kYBuqZ5I6gYJ4HyFe10PPC5zyjAN4xwLUWiOu1G7BC2Jwuj6

and when i hit from python 
password = 123456
hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt(10))
it return me this: $2b$10$KefWWC7IwzNOZjMg2YOT3eKJjAZLM/s84AOv0IH/QNEknMeIYMZWW
```

How can i get same request ?

Comment: Bcrypt generates different hashes every time. Use the password verify methods in Php/Python to check if a password matches a hash

Comment: Ok i want to hit laravel api through django rest  framework  can i do this and how?

Comment: I have same issue..any solution to this problem?